# Add a filter in views page

Tags: 7, views

I'm new in Drupal and i have crated a view for content type doctors who have many fields and i choose just some fields to be displayed in the view. Now i want to add a new filter like a select list in my page to select the country of doctor.

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter using the field (eg field_country), and select 'Dropdown' under settings. If this is a taxonomy term, select 'Expose this filter', then select 'Is one of' as the operator, and save. This will give you the drop down list.

If it is not a taxonomy term, the sequence might vary slightly, but it will be substantially the same.

Comment: To get a dropdown, you need a multivalues base for the field, like a taxonomy term or a location:country field, either with a predefined list of countries. Remove your current field, create a vocbulary 'Country', and add a few country names. If you make the vocabulary single level and autotagging, then your users will be able to add other countries.

Comment: so it's impossible to expose a none taxonomy field in a drop down list with the available values in the contents types already added (for me doctors)

Comment: Right. If you are currently defining the select list in a list field, move the values to a vocabulary, and change the field to a term reference field.

Comment: But for new doctors i have to add the new country first in the country vocabulary. there is no solution to add directly the field country ?

Comment: Use an autocomplete widget for input. Set the vocabulary for tagging, and you can add the country as you add the doctor.

Comment: But how to display just the available country in the exposed filter ? because i have added 10 country to the vocabulary but for the content type doctor i have just 3 country and i want the exposed filter country display me just the 3 country not 10